# Create readable words after binarization

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract

I am using opencv with Python to cleanup images to be readable for tesseract. I have a black and white image, and after adaptive thresholding, it doesn't look good enough. There is a lot of paper noise and letters are not so clean. How can I fix it?

adaptiveThreshold method:

```
cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
```

source:

[image: source]

after adaptiveThreshold:

[image: after adaptiveThreshold]

also I tried erosion and dilation:

```
kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
e = cv2.erode(roi_sharpen, kernel, iterations=1))
d = cv2.dilate(roi_sharpen, kernel, iterations=1))
```

results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can apply noise filtering (e.g. gaussian filter) before or after binarization. Also you can use edge detection filter (e.g. Canny) instead of adaptive threshold to extract edges.

Comment: I tried. But it worse :/

Comment: combination of errode and dilate might do the trick

Comment: I tried. But probably I do not use it correct :/ It's completely unreadable.

Comment: Could you try using tesseract for OCR? I've had a lot of success with it in the past.

Comment: I want to. But first i need to create readable image. On my source tesseract made a lot of mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you noticed that there's lots of noise, it's always a good idea to try some smoothing to the image.

For example, you can apply a gaussian filter to the original image

```
smooth_img = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0, 0)
bin_img = cv.adaptiveThreshold(smooth_img, 255, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2)
```

I tried a few kernel sizes, seems 5 by 5 kernel gave the best result on this example

[image: Binary image with Gaussian blur first]

If you don't like the small dots in the image, you can further apply a median filter to remove them

```
clean_img = cv.medianBlur(bin_img, 3)
```

You will get

[image: After median filter]

There are also lots of parameter tuning for Tesseract too, if you don't get satisfying result, you might want to try a few different Tesseract settings.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your answer. It's helpful.